# Angular | Get one row from Firebase

Tags: angular, database, typescript, firebase

I have problem with geting one record from realtime database (Firebase).
I am active in Angular and linked to firebase.

I get all record but I can't get one of them.

**Service file:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { User } from '../shared/user';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CrudService {
  usersRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  userRef: AngularFireObject<any>;
 
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
  
  // Read User
  GetStudent(id: string) {
    this.userRef = this.db.object('users/' + id);
    return this.userRef;
  }

  // Read Users List
  GetUsersList() {
    this.usersRef = this.db.list('users');
    return this.usersRef;
  }  

}
```

**User page component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { CrudService } from '../shared/crud.service';
import { User } from './../shared/user'; 



@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-page',
  templateUrl: './user-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-page.component.css']
})
export class UserPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private crudApi: CrudService) {}

  User: User[];

  ngOnInit() {
    let userid = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.userid; //ID User from URL

    this.crudApi.GetStudent(userid).snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
    })
  }
}
```

**How can I get one record?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't know if this is the best solution but it works!**

I did it the easiest way. I just wrote the id in the object path and it works!

```
user: any[];

this.db.object('users/'+userid).valueChanges().subscribe(user => {
  this.user = [];
  this.user.push(user);
  console.log(this.user);
})
```